# setBackgroundMessageHandler is not called in terminated state IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase/messaging in my react-native application to receive notifications from firebase.

When a message is received, i'll process the data and update my badge count. At the android device everything works perfect in foreground, background and terminated state. In iOS foreground and background is working fine. When the app is terminated/quit, and any other application is running in foreground. I receive a notification but firebase setBackgroundMessageHandler event is not called. I've already added 'content-available' : true in notification payload but the event is not called when another application is in foreground state. And when I open my application, setBackgroundMessageEvent is called and another duplicate message receive in the app.

Kindly help me to fix this issue. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Your app is terminated, so it isn't running, so it can't do anything.

Comment: I quit the application, received a notification, setMessageBackgroundHandler is called and everything is working fine. As I open another application. My app notified me, but now setMessageBackgroundHandler is not being called. Is it relatable to the resource-allocation priority of iOS ?

Answer (score -3):

I understand the issue now. It appears that you are facing a challenge with handling notifications in a killed state on iOS, specifically related to sending "data-only" messages with the appropriate APNs headers and the content-available flag to trigger the background handler.

If you wish to perform a task or make an API call when a notification is received in the killed or terminated state, you should consider sending two separate notifications. The first notification should include a payload with the notification part, ensuring that it triggers the notification popup for iOS even when the app is in the background or killed state. The second notification will be a "data-only" message, and it must include the necessary APNs headers as well as the content-available flag. This configuration is essential to activate the background handler.

For instance, when using the Node.js firebase-admin package to send a "data-only" message to an iOS device, make sure to structure your payload accordingly. This approach allows you to achieve the desired behavior of displaying a notification when the app is in the background or killed state and triggering the background handler for further processing.

It's crucial to pay attention to the details of the payload structure, including the use of content-available and the necessary APNs headers, to ensure proper functionality. Testing in different scenarios, including foreground, background, and killed states, is recommended to validate that your implementation behaves as expected.

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, AppState } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('====================================');
  console.log({ 'in kill state': remoteMessage });
  // api call for status update
// you can perform you desired task
});
function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  console.log('background is called', isHeadless);
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return <FakeView />;
  }

  return <App />;
}

const FakeView = () => {
  return null;
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
// Register the Headless task
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
  'RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage',
  () => HeadlessCheck,
);
```

Here is the payload that I send from the server:

```
    const message = {
    notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
  },
  data: { campaignId: campaignId, title: title, body: body },
  token: registrationId,
  android: {
    priority: 'high',
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: body,
      sound: 'default',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        sound: 'default',
        'content-available': 1,
      },
    },
    headers: {
      'apns-priority': '5',
    },
  },
};
```